# Where do monsters that wake you up come from in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, are the monsters that wake you up when you sleep in a bed in an unsafe location monsters that already exist and were moved from a dark location, or are they monsters which are spawned given that the game found a path from a dark location?

Comment: Note: This question is **obsolete** as of Minecraft 1.0.0; if you succeed in going to sleep, you will get a full night's sleep.

Comment: I also noticed that when we were 2 people on the server, only one had to go to sleep in order to cycle back to daytime. Is this a bug, or a feature of 1.0 now?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Please ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are newly spawned monsters that can find a path from a location that supports them spawning.

There is [some great research](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?p=2871535#p2871535) on this by bugi74:

> Every time bed(s) become active, all
>   players are gone through one by one,
>   each player given 20 tries of spawning
>   a monster. The normal "monsters do not
>   spawn near player" seems to not apply.
>
> On each try it will roll a random
>   monster type from the subset of
>   skeleton, spider or zombie, and a
>   random start location upto +/-32
>   blocks in horizontal directions and
>   upto +/-16 blocks vertical from the
>   players sleeping location. Then it
>   seeks downwards from that position for
>   the first opaque block below the
>   current block to be checked. Then it
>   tries if the place is suitable for the
>   monster to spawn (water for water
>   mobs, etc.) but no light level check
>   (yet), seeking upwards if the block is
>   not suitable. (There is a limits of 16
>   blocks above player position for how
>   high it will seek.) Should a suitable
>   location be found, there is another
>   check for if the mob can spawn there,
>   this time with light level check.
>
> Next the algorithm tries to calculate
>   a path from the found spot to the
>   player. If the last point along the
>   path is less than 1.5blocks away from
>   player's position in all three
>   coordinates, the mob gets spawned on a
>   spot very very near the player (like
>   half a block away) (that's what allows
>   the "warp through walls"), and all
>   kinds of things are set in motion
>   (like waking up and aggro), and no
>   further tries are done for that player
>   that time.
>
> The two cases where the monster gets
>   that close to player are when the path
>   is only blocked by one block thick
>   (thin?) wall and the bed (or suitable
>   section of it) is against that wall,
>   or when it really finds a route to the
>   player. No idea how smart the pathing
>   algorithm is - I don't think it is
>   anything near A* or better, judging
>   how stupid they are when trying to get
>   to player in normal situations
>   (luckily for us!).

I've got a [Bukkit plugin that manages sleeping with AFK players](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/14703/) that caused me to look in to all this myself.

Comment: Thank you! This is a complete answer. In fact, it's also an answer to my question [Can you be woken up by a creeper](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24010/can-you-be-woken-up-by-a-creeper-in-minecraft) — could you post a version of this answer there?

Answer (score 7):

It is a new mob that spawns to punish you for having a dumb bed location. Easy test;

1) Switch mode to peaceful, this clears out all the monsters

2) Switch back to normal and sleep in an unsafe bed

3) Monster spawns immediately

We can see that this monster is freshly spawned, because time doesn't actually elapse while your sleeping (but instead, the game just sets the time of day to morning), so a mob couldn't have "spawned" followed by "teleported to you". We can witness this lack of time-lapse by noticing that furnaces don't smelt while you're sleeping, for example (this might have been fixed in a recent patch? but I don't think so).

Answer (score 0):

From the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed#Behavior):

> If a hostile mob can get within 2 blocks of the bed, even if the blocks are separated by a wall, you will be awakened with the hostile mob standing next to you. There appears to be a slight delay before the mob attacks you, giving you time to get the first blow.

So it appears that it's not a spawning issue, it's an issue of "can the mob physically get to the 'unsafe to sleep' position from where it spawns".

Comment: That criteria is used to determine whether a bed is "safe", but the monster that actually appears is a fresh spawn, not something that simply walked up.  You can be awoken in a dark, sealed room even though monsters cannot spawn within 24 blocks of the player and cannot simply walk into the room.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that technically "spawning" rules just change when you're sleeping?  Since they're now "spawning" within the range that they normally wouldn't be able to.

Comment: @Ben Blank: If that's true, it's an answer to my question, and please post it as one so I can accept it, but are you **certain** it's a *new* mob and not a *teleported* mob? A description of how you verified this would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Tchalvak — Exactly.  @Kevin Reid — I didn't want to post a mostly-duplicate answer that came to the opposite conclusion.  I'll try to dig up the relevant section of the source; if I find it before Dave updates his answer, I'll post my own.

Comment: @Ben Blank - only the first @<username> reference currently generates a 'ping' to a given user (just an FYI).