# Can you be woken up by a creeper in prerelease versions of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In alpha and beta versions of Minecraft (prior to Minecraft's 1.0 release), if you attempt to go to sleep in an 'unsafe' area, there is a chance you will be woken up by an enemy mob.

If you sleep in a bed which is unsafe according to the game's rules but does not actually have an ordinary path to a dark area, is it ever possible to be woken up by a creeper, with the attendant risk of damage to structures?

I ask because I have slept in a somewhat-unsafe bed many times, and only ever met a zombie or skeleton, but never a creeper or spider, and I want to know whether I've just been lucky so far.

Comment: Note: This question is **obsolete** as of Minecraft 1.0.0; if you succeed in going to sleep, you will get a full night's sleep.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **The 'wake up' mechanic was removed in [Minecraft Release 1.0](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.0.0).**
> This answer is only relevant for versions of Minecraft built prior to that revision, accessible using the Minecraft Launcher's [Time Machine](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_launcher#Time_Machine) functionality.

---

No, a creeper can not wake you up/be a nightmare.

The results would be catastrophic and are therefore disallowed just like a creeper mob spawner does not exist for the same reason.

bugi74 has done [some great research](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?p=2871535#p2871535) on the code itself which verifies this:

> On each try it will roll a random monster type from the subset of skeleton, spider or zombie

Comment: Good point! If monster spawners exclude creepers, then it makes more sense that beds might too.

Comment: I just added a quote from the guy that verified this by picking apart the code himself.

Comment: but hacked in mob spawners spawn pigs, so do hacked in beds cause pig nightmares?

Comment: Hrm... Then would hacked in beds in the nether produce dreams of cooked bacon?

Comment: A creeper spawner wouldn't actually last long enough to make much difference. ;)

Answer (score 9):

"Unsafe according to the game's rules but does not actually have an ordinary path to a dark area" seem mutually exclusive.  If a hostile mob can get within 2 blocks of the bed (even through walls) there is the possibility of being woken up.

I have seen numerous posts on the [minecraft forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/187701-creepers-creepin-in-my-house/) referencing being woken up by a creeper/spider but [bugi74's interpretation of the source code](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/176636-science-experimenting-with-beds-how-to-make-a-safe-bed/page__st__40__p__2803021#entry2803021) suggests that creepers cannot spawn.

[image]

Image from Minecraft Wiki

Comment: It is completely safe to stand next to the bottom right bed forever. It is not safe to sleep on it because of a bug in Minecraft. I am talking about the mobs Minecraft teleports into your house-with-an-unsafe-bed when you sleep: can they ever be a creeper?

Comment: Yes it could be any hostile mob including creepers.

Comment: That'sssssssssss a nice bed you got there, what a ssssssshame... **BOOM**

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: Have you personally seen a creeper appearing next to your unsafe bed?

Comment: I've never ever woken up to a creeper. Obviously the consequences of that would be far worse than any other mob, so maybe it is specifically disallowed.

Comment: I have not personally had a creeper spawn next to my bed but I have seen many forum posts complaining about creepers spawning while sleeping.

Comment: -1: No freehand circles! Joking, +1, very nice illustration!

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - Has the question changed since this answer was posted? I find this does not answer the question as it is currently worded.

Comment: I added sources for the conflicting evidence that I have found.